# Generating istanbul/nyc coverage reports with mocha

Tags: mocha.js, bamboo, istanbul

I am trying to generate an nyc/istanbul coverage report on my project (using mocha).  I can get this to run from the command line with the following command:

`npm test --reporter mocha-bamboo-reporter test/`

which is essentially running

`nyc mocha --recursive "mocha-bamboo-reporter" "test/"`

The tricky part is that I need to run this in bamboo which doesn't seem to support chaining of/multiple commands in one task.

My bamboo config has a mocha test runner:

`node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --reporter mocha-bamboo-reporter --recursive`

I have an istanbul/nyc instrument task:

`./node_modules/nyc/bin/nyc.js instrument test/ .nyc_output`

And then a coverage report task:

`./node_modules/nyc/bin/nyc.js report`

When this runs I get no data in the report file:

```
25-Apr-2018 14:27:28    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
25-Apr-2018 14:27:28    File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
25-Apr-2018 14:27:28    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
25-Apr-2018 14:27:28    All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
25-Apr-2018 14:27:28    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  The best way to do it was to create a custom script within my package.json file and then call that from Bamboo.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "test-ci": "nyc -a --reporter=clover mocha --recursive --reporter mocha-bamboo-reporter"
```

**Bamboo - Node.js task**

```
run-script test-ci
```